# Libgdx - Why is one AssetManager running and another not

Tags: java, libgdx, assets, asset-management

I have set up two static instances of AssetManager

One for 2d assets and one for 3d assets.

The 3d one works fine, however, the 2d one doesn't. It seems that it is not calling manager.update().

As shown on the [wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets), the update function is called when the manager has finished loading. But the 2d manager's update function is not being called.

I do not get why.

I don't think it is the way I set up the managers because both managers look identical (except for the identifier, of course)

Please explain why this is happening

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show some code please, you could have made an error that you are not seeing yourself.

Comment: The `update` method is NOT called, when the `AssetManager` finished to load the assets, but you have to call `AssetManager#update()` to keep loading! If you don't want to call `update` every time, you might use `finishLoading`, which will wait until everything is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

@Springrbua is correct, I must call assetLoader.finishLoading(), or else the loading will not be completed